# Different functionalities of button[] at each click on a particular button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, buttonclick

I have an array of button created dynamically, suppose 8 buttons, what I want is that when I click a particular button its background picture is changed and the name of button is stored in a linked list. When I click the same button again the background picture goes back to the original and the button name is deleted from linked list. Now I am able to do the first part, the second click is not working as I want it to.

Basically it's a datastructures project (shopping store) therefore I am using linked list, I have a linked list whose content is displayed through picture boxes[] and labels. Here what i am trying to do is when I click the picture box, the content of that particular node is added to a new linked list (added to the cart) and when I click on the picturebox again that particular item is deleted from the linked list (removed from the cart). Clicking it for the first time it is doing what i want it to do but the second click is not really working.

It's a datastructures project therefore I can't really use any built in classes for linked list, I had to write all methods myself and I did and they work.

```
cb[i].Click += (sender, e)=>{

if (flag == 0) {
   // Console.WriteLine(obj.Retrieve(index).NodeContent);
   // Console.WriteLine(obj.Retrieve(index).number);
   inv.Add(obj.Retrieve(index).NodeContent, obj.Retrieve(index).number);
   bill += Convert.ToInt32(obj.Retrieve(index).number);
   cb[index].Image = Image.FromFile(@"F:\uni work\3rd semester\project images\rcart.jpg");
   flag++;
}
else if (flag == 1)
{
   // Console.WriteLine(bill);
   bill -= Convert.ToInt32(obj.Retrieve(index).number);
   // Console.WriteLine(bill);
   inv.Delete(index);
   cb[index].Image = Image.FromFile(@"F:\uni work\3rd semester\project images\cart.png");
   flag--;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code and explain a) where the problem is and b) why you use a linked list instead of a List<Button>.

Comment: What are you having problems with? removing the picture or removing the item from the LinkedList?

Comment: Please can you clarify if this is WinForms, ASP.NET web forms etc. Detail what you what your problem is (what it is doing, or is not doing) and what you have tried so far. Include code samples if possible, consider a minimal reproducible sample at https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @TaW i am using button array, linked list store the names which are to be given to the buttons

Comment: @MarkHall i am having problem with removing item from linked list

Comment: Please show the code you are using to remove it, if my answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: @MarkHall i got it.. thank you..your code was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a LinkedList it does have  a [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcahk87c(v=vs.110).aspx) Method and a [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k87xw3hb(v=vs.110).aspx) Method that take a string. You haven't specified exactly what your problem is this should work. When you assign images to a control you loose the information that tells you what Image it is.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Button b = new Button() { Height = 30, Width = 70, Location = new Point(i, 50 * i),Name = "NewButton" + (i + 1).ToString() , Tag=i};
            b.Click += b_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(b);
        }
    }

    void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Button b = (Button)sender;
        if(myList.Contains(b.Name)) //Check if button is in the List then Change Picture and remove
        {
            b.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Peg_Blue;
            myList.Remove(b.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            b.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Peg_Red;
            myList.AddLast(b.Name);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a class for each button, containing the two images and switch between them on each click?